# Swing Components Doubling

Tags: java, swing

So I am trying to create a simple paint program and I have been having a problem. The program has a window, on the left of the window is a bar with pen size control, and the rest of the window is the drawing pane. However, whenever I draw on the pane, the side bar is basically copied onto the pane, but it can be drawn over.

Here is my CHPaint class (main):

```
package paint;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CHPaint{
JFrame frame;
JLabel penSizeLabel;
PaintPanel panel;
JButton upButton;
JButton downButton;
JPanel left;
JPanel main;


int penSize = 1;

public static void main(String[] args){
    CHPaint gui = new CHPaint();
    System.out.println("gui built");
    gui.go();
}

public void go() {
    frame = new JFrame("Caleb's Paint");
    panel = new PaintPanel();
    upButton = new JButton("Up");
    downButton = new JButton("Down");
    penSizeLabel = new JLabel("Size: " + penSize);
    left = new JPanel();
    main = new JPanel();


    panel.addMouseListener(new Painting());
    panel.addMouseMotionListener(new Painting());
    upButton.addActionListener(new UpButton());
    downButton.addActionListener(new DownButton());

    left.setLayout(new BoxLayout(left, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    left.add(upButton);
    left.add(penSizeLabel);
    left.add(downButton);

    left.setBackground(Color.gray);
    penSizeLabel.setBackground(Color.gray);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, main);
    main.add(BorderLayout.WEST, left);
    main.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}


class UpButton implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        panel.changePenSize(1);
        penSize++;
        penSizeLabel.setText("Size: " + penSize);
    }
}
class DownButton implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        panel.changePenSize(-1);
        if (penSize > 1){
            penSize--;
        }
        penSizeLabel.setText("Size: " + penSize);
    }
 }
class Painting implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        panel.draw(e.getX(), e.getY());

    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        panel.draw(e.getX(), e.getY());
    }               
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        panel.mouseUp();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}    
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}      
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {} 
}
```

}

Here is the class for the drawing panel:

```
package paint;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
    int drawX = -10;
    int drawY = -10;
    int oldX = -10;
    int oldY = -10;
    int penSize = 1;


    public void draw(int x, int y){
            oldX = drawX;
            oldY = drawY;
            drawX = x;
            drawY = y;
            this.repaint();
    }
    public void mouseUp(){
            oldX = -10;
            oldY = -10;
            drawX= -10;
            drawY= -10;
    }
    public void changePenSize(int p){
            if (penSize > 0){
                    penSize = penSize+p;
            }
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            if (oldX != -10 && (oldY) != -10){                      // If you didn't just start or lift the pen
                    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(penSize, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                    g.drawLine(oldX, oldY, drawX, drawY);
            } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                    g.fillOval(drawX-(penSize/2), drawY-(penSize/2), penSize, penSize);
            }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I didn't know the rules here for posting, please forgive me D:. Also, I didn't know what part of the code messed it up so I didn't know what I should cut out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your code in the forum, not on pastebin. Also, the code you post should be in the form of a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). If I had to guess, which I do since the code is not posted here, I would say that you didn't invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` at the top of your painting method, so you are seeing garbage.

Comment: _"EDIT:.."_ - Still, post your code here.

Comment: `I didn't know what part of the code messed it up so I didn't know what I should cut out.` - that is one of the reasons for creating a SSCCE. You remove code until it works or still demonstrates the problem. If it still doesn't work then you have a SSCCE to post. If it starts working then you know the problem is with the code you have deleted which will help you debug or describe the problem better. You still haven't added the `super.paintComponent()` to your code.

Answer (score 1):

This won't solve your problem but the following is not used anymore:

```
main.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel); // read the API for more info
```

You should be using:

```
main.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `super.paintComponent()` in your `paintComponent()` method. Among other things, this will clear the JPanel for you.

Comment: Yes, this was suggested 3 hours before this answer and restated 7 minutes before this answer was posted. Why clutter the forum? Force the OP to pay attention to comments that have been made.